# How to comment out structure <?= ?> in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

a trivial question, but all my efforts to comment out code lines like this:

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'bew_id')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Bew']) ?>
```

failed by using PHP and/or HTML-comments.Following trys didn't success:

//

/* */

<-!- -->

Any ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `<?=` to `<?php` and then do the comment

```
<?php /*echo  $form->field($model, 'bew_id')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Bew']) */ ?>
```

because this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'bew_id')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Bew']) ?>
```

is shorthand  for

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'bew_id')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Bew']) ?>
```

use any comment  // or /* */

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<?=` at the beginning then you can comment by using `<!--` as follows

```
<!---$form->field($model, 'bew_id')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Bew']) ?>-->
```